# I am trying to build a facebook clone dapp using solana and next js. I followed the tutorial but i still run into this error

Tags: next.js, solana, decentralized-applications

[I followed the tutorial yet this error isn't being solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qNEF.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qNEF.jpg)

I tried to use {} instead of [] but still the same error occurs

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

your useContext return null. And you try to destructure null. If you don't provide array in context provider value then you **can't** write:

```
const [a1, a2] = ....
```

So probably you miss match useState

```js
const [state, setState] = useState
```

with context

```js
const context = useContext(Context)
```

So. Just write:

```js
const balance = useContext(BalanceContext);
console.log('balance context:',balance)
```

and then you will see what is in balance context.
if is a object then you have to destructure object.

ps.
quick fix to run project:

```js
const [balance, setBalanace] = useContext(BalanceContext) || [];
// balance and setBalance is undefined
```